# prawn-table set header's row background color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

```
pdf.table([header, row1, row2], width: 490, cell_style: { size: 7, align: :center }) do
  style(row(0), padding: [4,2], font: "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf")
  # style(row(0).columns(2..3), width: 10 )
  # style(row(0), cell_style: {background_color: "#f5f5dc"} )
  style(row(1), padding: [16,10])
  style(row(1).columns(-2..-1), align: :right)
  style(row(2).column(0), borders: [])
  style(row(2).column(-2..-1), padding: [6,10], align: :right)
end
```

I want `row(0)` to have a background color, but can't find out how (see the commented out lines - those are not working).

I use [prawn-rails](https://github.com/Whoops/prawn-rails) and [prawn-table](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table) gems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.. I am too quick with asking questions.

Here is [how you do that](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table/blob/master/manual/table/row_colors.rb) (use `row_colors` option):

```
pdf.table([header, row1, row2], width: 490, cell_style: { size: 7, align: :center}, row_colors: ['F0F0A3', nil, nil]) do
  style(row(0), padding: [4,2], font: "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf")
  style(row(1), padding: [16,10])
  style(row(1).columns(-2..-1), align: :right)
  style(row(2).column(0), borders: [])
  style(row(2).column(-2..-1), padding: [6,10], align: :right)
end
```

I don't think, it is the best way to achieve the header's background color, but what I did is just set the colors for each row (actually color for the first row, and nil for each left).