# Undefined method error when :align => {0 => :left, 1 => :right} in Prawn-table is set

Tags: html, prawn

I receive this error whenever I set `:align => {0 => :left, 1 => :right}` in `Prawn-table`:

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

My table is setup like this:

```
conds = [[{:content => "<b><font size='20'>Condensers</font></b>", :colspan => 2}], [ "Model #", "Price"]]
conds += @customer.condensers.map do |condenser|
[
condenser.model_number,
number_to_currency(condenser.price / 0.55)
]
end
pdf.table conds,
row_colors: ["FFFFFF","d8edff"],
:header => true,
:width => 300,
:cell_style => { :inline_format => true, :rotate => 0, :overflow => :shrink_to_fit, :min_font_size => 8, :align => {0 => :left, 1 => :right} }
```

Comment: what is the error msg?

Comment: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: give the backtrace  and line number..

Comment: /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/customers/show.pdf.prawn where line #22 raised: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: this is line 22 pdf.table conds

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from a post by [Andrey Deineko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733061/prawn-table-set-headers-row-background-color?rq=1) which works great!

```
pdf.table(conds) do
  style(column(1), align: :right)
end
```